# prove that $U_{51}$,$U_{80}$ are not isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I need prove the next result:

$U(\mathbb{Z}/51\mathbb{Z})$,$U(\mathbb{Z}/80\mathbb{Z})$ are not isomorphic.

thanks for your help!

Comment: You asked two very similar questions almost instantly. It is much better to ask one, wait for the answer (hopefully thereby getting some illumination) and *then* ask the other. Who knows, by that time you might not even need to ask it!

Comment: What are $U_{51}$ and $U_{80}$? This notation is widely used for 51th and 80th roots of unit. But in this case, the result is pretty obvious ;)

Comment: yes, I know... my questions are similar. But is my first time, I really don't know how this works

Comment: That's why I am explaining it :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$U(Z/51Z)\cong U(Z/3Z)\oplus{U(Z/17Z)}\cong Z/Z2\oplus{Z/Z16},$$
$$U(Z/80Z)\cong U(Z/5Z)\oplus{U(Z/16Z)}\cong Z/Z4\oplus{(Z/Z2\oplus{Z/Z4)}},$$
U(Z/3Z) and $U(Z/17Z)$ and $U(Z/5Z)$ all have primitive roots,but $U(Z/16Z)$ does not.

Comment: Im sorry, I been forgot much of group theory... why this implies that there is no isomorphism?

Comment: The rank of $U(Z/51Z)$ is 2,but the rank of $U(Z/80Z)$ is 3

Comment: you right. I have to say, I did not know the concept of rank of a group (jeje) But now, I see that you answer have a lot of sense. tanks